# How do I program a greatest common divisor program is 80x86 assembly?

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, greatest-common-divisor

I know there are different methods to finding the gcd of two numbers, but I want to know which is best given assembly's commands and how do I implement the method into the program?

Here's what I have so far:

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT

INCLUDE io.h            ; header file for input/output

.STACK 4096

.DATA
number1 DWORD ?
number2 DWORD ?
prompt1 BYTE "Please enter an integer for X", 0
prompt2 BYTE "Please enter an integer for Y", 0
string BYTE 40 DUP (?)
resultLbl BYTE "The greatest common divisor of X and Y is", 0
gcd BYTE 11 DUP (?), 0

.CODE
_MainProc PROC
    input prompt1, string, 40
    atod string
    mov number1, eax

    input prompt2, string, 40
    atod string
    mov number2, edx

    mov eax, number1
    mov edx, number2

Get_GCD:
    xchg eax,edx
    cmp eax,edx
    jb Get_GCD
    sub eax,edx
    test edx,edx
    jnz Get_GCD
    ret

    dtoa gcd, edx
    output resultLbl, gcd

    mov eax, 0
    mov edx, 0
    ret
_MainProc ENDP
END                             ; end of source code
```

I run it and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ret that is after jnz Get_GCD and before the dtoa. The Euclid subtraction algorithm loop can be shortened:

```
;                                       ;eax and edx are the numbers
gcd0:   cmp     edx,eax                 ;edx = smaller number
        jb      gcd1
        xchg    eax,edx
gcd1:   sub     eax,edx                 ;subtract smaller from larger
        jnz     gcd0                    ;loop if not done
;                                       ;edx = gcd
```

Note that the worst case for the above loop is eax = 0xffffffff and edx = 1, where it takes 4 billion loops to complete. Euclid's modulo algorithm shown below, uses division, but the worst case number of loops n is: n <= 5 log10 (smaller number) or n <= 1.50515 log2 (smaller number). For 32 bit unsigned integers, the worst case is two fibonacci numbers, 1836311903 and 2971215073 (gcd = 1), where the number of loops = 45 which is <= 5 log10(1836311903) (~= 46.32).

Euclid modulo method:

```
;                                       ;eax and ebx are the numbers
        cmp     ebx,eax                 ;ebx = smaller number
        jb      gcd0
        xchg    eax,ebx
gcd0:   xor     edx,edx                 ;divide: larger / smaller
        div     ebx
        mov     eax,ebx                 ;eax = new larger (was smaller)
        mov     ebx,edx                 ;ebx = new smaller (new remainder)
        or      ebx,ebx                 ;loop if new smaller != 0
        jnz     gcd0
;                                       ;eax = gcd
```

Answer (score -1):

```
include Irvine32.inc

    .data

factor  DWORD 60
i       DWORD 2
largest DWORD ?

str1    BYTE "Greatest common factor",0

    .code 
    main PROC

top:    
    mov eax,factor
    mov ebx,i
    xor edx,edx
    div ebx
    call writedec
    cmp ebx,eax
    je L2
    call crlf
    cmp eax,factor
    jb L1
    inc i
    jmp top
L1:
    mov largest,ebx    
L2:
    mov eax,largest
    mov edx,OFFSET str1
    call writestring
    call writedec

    exit

    main ENDP
    END main
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on how this is supposed to solve any problem(s) that you found in the code posted in the question? Code dumps don't make for particularly good answers.

Comment: I'm with Michael on this. Dumping the answer (code only) to your homework assignment here doesn't help (your answer originally wasn't even readable), and used a library the original question didn't use. I've down voted this answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
Get_GCD:
    xchg EAX,EDX
    cmp EAX,EDX
    jb Get_GCD
    sub EAX,EDX
    test EDX,EDX
    jnz Get_GCD
    ret
```